# MultiSelectListPreference with prerequisites

Tags: android, android-multiselectlistpreference

First thing first, sorry for my English, I am not a native speaker.

---

What I want to achieve is the following: I have a checkbox for option A in my preferences xml, and I have two (or more) options A.1, A.2, ..., A.n that have option A as a prerequisite. If one of the options A.n is checked, option A has to be checked automatically. Is this possible, and if yes, how can i do that?

Example:

> Option A
>   Option A.1
>   Option A.2 ...

If Option A.1 is checked, i want something along the lines like this:

> X Option A
>   X Option A.1
>   Option A.2

I tried using a MultiSelectListPreference to do this.

Comment: yes you, acknowledge i understand it right?
you want the status of all previous check boxes ?
i.e if you select 5th place then it will return previous 4 plus current status.

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan Nope, only the top option A.

Comment: Add your code.....

Comment: Currently i am using an .xml to definde my preference screen, so sadly i got no code to show in this matter.